# converting docx document to pdf with docx4j not the same

Tags: java, pdf, docx, docx4j

Good evening!
I convert from a docx document programatically (java docx4j)  to pdf.

I get the pdf document from my docx document but the pdf is not exactly the same as the docx document. (lines between numbers are lost and no bold headline, please see the attachted documents)

If you compare the docx and the pdf document  two differences are there. 1) the headlines in pdf are not anymore bold and 2) more important under number nine (§9) there is no new lines betweenn the numbers (1),(2),(3). in pdf but in docx there are.

How can i produce the same pdf from my docx file? 
Thanks in advance

http://www.janolaw.de/export/LivingWillGeneratedByMe.pdf

http://www.janolaw.de/export/LivingWillorg.docx

Comment: Are you using docx4j 2.8.1, or a current snapshot?  If the former, please try the latter, since there have been significant changes.

Comment: hi jason,  it is not 2.8.1, this is what i user docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-nightly-20131008.jar

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "no new lines between the numbers (1),(2),(3)", it appears w:br is not being handled correctly.

I've created https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/90 to track this.

**Update** fixed in [docx4j 3.0 beta 2](http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3_0-beta2.zip)

Comment: I am losing styles of text in tables. Any idea why that may happen?